# React onSubmit passing props

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass props to handle submit to setState for the first imgUrl and stra, then call the event and set the second state but i keep getting an error saying

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

So i am not sure what I am doing wrong at the moment. Please help and thank you in advance

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imgUrl: '',
            stra: '',
            openForm: false,
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.closeForm = this.closeForm.bind(this);
        // this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit = (stra, imgUrl) => {
        this.setState({strain: stra, imgUrl: imgUrl})

        return event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            this.setState({openForm: true})
        }
        // e.preventDefault();
        
    }


render() {
                                    <p className='px-5 '>
                                        <a onClick={this.handleSubmit('Bue', SimpleBlack)} class="btn btn-primary btn-full" href="#">Request</a>
                                    </p>
}
```

Comment: `this.setState({strain: stra, imgUrl: imgUrl})` when is this supposed to happen? When the button is clicked, or something else? It's currently happening during render, which is why you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
handleSubmit = (stra, imgUrl) => {
    const self = this;

     .....

    this.setState({strain: stra, imgUrl: imgUrl},
          () => {
                    .....
                         Place here what you want 
                         to be done just before
                         opening the form but after stra and imgUrl 
                         get their respective state values
                    .....

                    self.setState({openForm: true})
          }
    );       
}
```

Basically, this is the use of the setState call back.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use setStateinside componentDidUpdate. The problem is that you are creating an infinite loop because there's no break condition.*

componentDidUpdate() is called after componentDidMount() and can be useful to perform some action when the state changes.
componentDidUpdate() takes as its first two arguments the previous props and the previous state.
Inside the method we can check if a condition is met and perform an action based on it.

For example, in the code below we check if the previous state and the current state are different. If they are, the console log statement will be run.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.pokemons !== this.state.pokemons) {
    console.log('pokemons state has changed.')
  }
}
```

**When do we use componentDidUpdate() ?**

An example of when to use componentDidUpdate() is when we need to call an external API on condition that the previous state and the current state have changed.

The call to the API would be conditional to the state being changed. If there is no state change, no API is called.

Like mentioned before, to avoid an infinite loop, the API call needs to be inside a conditional statement.